# iOS on-click highlight section of an image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an image and I would like to have it so when I click on a section of the image, only that section highlights. At present to test this, I have set up an application and placed an image view on the back. I just created an image and wrote 1,2,3 and 4 on it. I then used a UIView to draw a horizontal and vertical line through the image

I have set up a on tap gesture listener and that prints out which section I have hit. Code below

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // Get the location of the touch
    CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:[self view]];

    if(touchPoint.x > 10 && touchPoint.x < 160)
    {

        if(touchPoint.y > 30 && touchPoint.y < 220)
        {
            NSLog(@"Button 1");


        }else if(touchPoint.y > 220 && touchPoint.y < 430){
            NSLog(@"Button 3");
        }

    }else if(touchPoint.x > 160 && touchPoint.x < 310)

    {
        if(touchPoint.y > 220 && touchPoint.y < 430)
        {
           NSLog(@"Button 4");
        }else if(touchPoint.y > 30 && touchPoint.y < 220){
            NSLog(@"Button 2");
        }

    }

   //For debugging
   // NSLog(@"x = %f y = %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
}
```

Now what I want to happen is when I click on a particular section, I want just that part of the image to highlight. Is this possible? At present the workaround I am using is adding 4 buttons on top of the grid which are hidden for normal state, and give them an image for highlighted state like this

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

And set the alpha to 0.5 or somewhere around that, so it looks like that section is being highlighted. If this is the only way it can be done, then just leave an answer saying so and I will accept it, but I would prefer a more concrete solution if one is available!! Thanks in advance

Example of image created
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the right approach.

Maybe you should use less hard coded numbers in your code and implement this functionality on a more general level (e.g., using the `frame` property of the image view or buttons).

Comment: Had a feeling this was probably the only real approach, but I guess if it works, it works, 


Yeah would make more sense to use the frame of the imageview, not sure why I was using the entire view.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this behavior for free, I believe, by going up the hierarchy and using UIControl instead. Subclass it and modify its highlighting behavior.

Comment: The UIControl subclass can contain the subviews with each mapped region of the image--be sure to their 'tag' property for later. Then, in UIControl, you can override the touch tracking methods and using GCRect and CGRectContainsPoint to determine if any of the subviews were selected and based on the new UIControl's internal state, you can  determine how to manipulate all the views to get your desired effects.

Comment: This may be slightly less efficient than the test you do above, but every view can be manipulated independently and can be queried by their frame property vs explicitly knowing their sizes and placement. The _major_ advantage of doing this is that you can write this up in one unique place, extend and reuse later. And if you need anything back in the main view's delegate, you can of course, send out events from the UIControl implementation to responders.